# How to change price value dynamically in magento

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento, magento-1.7

I am a beginner in Magento. I want to change the price value in product detail page dynamically using ajax. In the meantime i want to calculate this price value in the cart page also

Refer this URL: 
http://dev.tangoprint.ch/magento/index.php/plakate/a1.html

This page contains a calculator to calculate a price value and dynamically I want to change price in the cart page as well.
Please refer this image:
[image]

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: According to what criteria you want to change ?

Comment: thank u sahal....i want to change my price value depending upon calculated value...for example :-if i got $100 in calculator means i want to change same value in product price..

Comment: Can you explain me what your calculator does ?

Comment: once again thank u sahal,calculator i want to change quantity of product and calculate its prices value depending upon quantity.which page i want to change sahal...?

Comment: further i want to change price value in cart page also....how can i change it....

Comment: check the below anserr. that will help you. You are changing the `price` value and when you `add to cart` it will reflect in cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Step 1 - include jQuery in page.xml (app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/page.xml)*

```
<action method="addJs"><script>jquery/jquery-1.5.2.no-conflict.min.js</script></action>
```

*Step 2 - add price calculation php page (/myscripts/ajaxPriceCal.php)*

```
<?php
include_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();

if(isset($_POST['qty']) && !empty($_POST['qty'])){

    $product_id = $_POST['pid'];
    $my_qty = $_POST['qty'];
    $my_price = 0;

    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

    $_tierPrices = $_product->tier_price;

    $_tierPrices = array_reverse($_tierPrices);

    for($i=0; $i < count($_tierPrices); $i++){
        if($my_qty >= $_tierPrices[$i]['price_qty']){
            $my_price = $_tierPrices[$i]['price'];        
            break;
        }
    }

    $calculated_price = $my_price*$my_qty;

    echo number_format($calculated_price,2,'.',',');
}
?>
```

*Step 3 - modify tier price qty text option page (app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml)*

add following script to the very beginning of text.phtml page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

function get_total_qty(){
    var qty = parseInt(0);
    var qty = $("#calculator_qty").val();
    /*
    * AJAX call
    */
    var quantity = parseInt($j('#qty').val()) + parseInt(qty); // get final quantity
    var product_id = $j('#prod_id').val(); // get product id
    $j.post("/magento/scripts/ajaxPriceCal.php", { qty: quantity, pid: product_id },
        function(data){
            $j('.price').html(data);
    });

}

$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('.calculate').click(function(){
        if($("#calculator_qty").val()){
            get_total_qty();
        }
    });    
});
</script>
```

This will help you. You are changing the `price` value and when you do `add to cart` it will reflect in cart.

Comment: hi sahal....can i create ajaxpricecal.php page ? otherwise please say path for this page........

Comment: Create a `myscript` folder in you root. root means where your `app`, `skin` folder exists. Put the `ajaxpricecal.php` in `myscript` folder

Comment: see you can understand it with include `Mage.php` in `ajaxpricecal.php` file.

Comment: hi sahal.....its working perfectly....thank a lot....i need to show it product details page also ah?...anything else?

Comment: No thats it, you are done. (I guess now you worked on product details page. In cart page you don't need to do anything)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23404/discussion-between-vivekdragon-and-sahal)